# Strain tensor of rigid body

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

If we have a particle that satisfies rigid body motion then its velocity $u$ is of the form $$u=a\times x+b$$ 
Why is its strain tensor zero?

The strain tensor is given by $$D(u)=\frac{1}{2} (\nabla u +\nabla u^t)$$

*See the answers for my attempt.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u$ can be written in the form 
$$u=Ax+b$$ where $A$ is a skew symmetric matrix. Then $\nabla u=A$ and consequently $$D(u)=\frac{1}{2} (A+A^t)=0$$

Comment: Yup, that’s correct. Great use of axial vector correspondence!

Answer (score 2):

The strain tensor is zero because an inertial (Galilean) observer moving in the same frame as the body wouldn’t see the object “deform” at all.

If we declare the strain to be a quantity that is frame-independent in classical mechanics, then it has to be zero in all frames when it is zero in one frame.

Comment: Can u also check my answer below as a mathematical point of view